# Why does visual studio code analysis warn me that this object can be disposed twice in this code (when it can't)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Code is:

```
using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memorystream))
    {
        writer.Write((double)100.0);
    }
    return memorystream.ToArray();
}
```

Isn't the above code appropriate to properly dispose of both object?

Is the code analysis at all useful? Other than garbage information about variables names and namespaces it seems to complain about a lot of things that are not reality. I am really thinking that maybe it is useful and I am just missing the point.

OKAY to address concerns whether the MemoryStream is disposed of or not (its not) here is an example where the VS code analysis gives me the exact same warning. Clearly nothing is getting disposed of here

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   public void DoSomethingElse()
    {

    }

   #region IDisposable Members
   public void Dispose()
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   #endregion
}

public class MyOtherClass : IDisposable
{
    public MyOtherClass(MyClass mc)
    {

    }
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

public void Foo()
{
    using (MyClass mc = new MyClass())
    {
        using (MyOtherClass otherclass = new MyOtherClass(mc))
        {
            otherclass.DoSomething();
        }
        mc.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: if I remember correctly, disposing a System.IO.*Writer also disposes the Stream it wraps.

Comment: What object? What is the exact warning message?

Comment: if that were true then the call to memorystream.ToArray() would throw an exception.

Comment: I believe the BinaryWriter when enclosed with using, causes the underlying stream (memorystream) to close/dispose along with it, since they are inter-dependent.    There should be some MSDN doc abou that.

Comment: Again... If the stream were disposed then how can I call memorystream.ToArray()?

Comment: You need to call .ToArray to save the results, then dispose the MemoryStream, then return the saved results.

Comment: @MatthewSanford - doing a quick test in LINQPad, I can still call ToArray on a memory stream after disposing it just fine. sshot @ http://i.imgur.com/l5UcA.png

Answer (score 0):

On "If the stream were disposed then how can I call memorystream.ToArray()" part of the question:

MemeoryStream.Dispose does not release internal buffer. The only thing that it does is blocking all Stream methods (like Read) by throwing "Object Disposed" exception. I.e. following code is perfectly valid (usually similar code accessing lower level storage can be written for other other Stream objects that manage some sort of storage):

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (memoryStream)
{
 // write something to the stream
}
// Note memoryStream.Write will fail here with an exception,
// only calls to get storage (ToArray and GetBuffer) make sense at this point.
var data = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: so... you are saying that it is disposed but has not released all its memory?? When exactly does this memorystream release its memory then?

Comment: MemoryStream is purely managed object, as result there would be no difference in memory usage whether it releases its internal buffer (managed byte[] object) during Dispose or not. Since the one of the main reasons to use MemoryStream is to create byte[] array with some binary data written to a stream not releasing the inner buffer during Dispose/Close call looks like valid and useful design decision on Framework folks part.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess I would say that the logic of the analysis rule is identifying a possiblity that goes someting like this:

*"You are passing a disposable object into the constructor of another disposable object (thus semantically implying a transfer of ownership). If ownership is truly being trasnsferred to the second object, it's likely that it will dispose of the object passed to its constructor in its own Dispose method but you're disposing of it as well."*

Your second example proves that it is not actually analysing whether or not the second object takes ownership of and disposes the first, but rather this rule is saying this pattern has some semantic ambiguity, as the code responsible for disposal of the first object is no longer clear.

The dispose pattern has all of the inherent pitfalls of alloc/free and new/delete as only one class should own and thus control the lifetime of a disposable instance.

All pure conjecture of course but that's how I'd read it.

Comment: Yes, code analysis in this case will be confused.  A good example are the compression streams e.g. GZipStream, which can take ownership of the underlying stream.  Code Analysis does not know this and will warn you.  In this case, the writer does NOT take ownership of the MemoryStream however.

Answer (score 0):

MemoryStream wraps a managed buffer that will be garbage collected at some point in the future regardless of whether its disposed of.

The IDisposable implementation is part of the Stream contract. It closes the stream preventing you from using the Read and Write methods but you are still permitted to access the underlying bytes. (Preventing calls to ToArray would probably make it difficult to use with StreamWriters.) A Stream implementation that does use unmanaged resources like a FileStream would release the file handle when it is disposed of.

The code analysis is noting that both you and the StreamWriter are calling Dispose on the same object and warning about it. This is pretty meaningless for a MemoryStream but might be dangerous with some other IDisposable implementations.

You appear to be confusing the IDisposable interface with garbage collection. Calling Dispose does not release managed objects, it just gives your class the opportunity to release unmanaged resources in a deterministic manner.

Answer (score 0):

BinaryWriter does not dispose the MemoryStream.  YOU NEED TO DISPOSE OF IT.  Get the results of .ToArray in a variable, then dispose the MemoryStream, then return the result.  Or use a try/finally to dispose of the MemoryStream.

Answer (score -1):

I think `BinaryWriter.Dispose()` will call its underlying `MemoryStream`'s `.Dispose()`, and then your `using` will re-dispose it.

At least I think that's what will happen. I haven't opened the source for `BinaryWriter` to verify, but I was always under the impression it closed and disposed its underlying stream.

---

*Edit:*

This is the source for the classes. You can see where your memory stream is being disposed:

*BinaryStream*:

```
    public BinaryWriter(Stream output) : this(output, new UTF8Encoding(false, true)) 
    {
    } 

    public BinaryWriter(Stream output, Encoding encoding)
    { 
        if (output==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");
        if (encoding==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encoding"); 
        if (!output.CanWrite)
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_StreamNotWritable")); 
        Contract.EndContractBlock(); 

        OutStream = output; 
        _buffer = new byte[16];
        _encoding = encoding;
        _encoder = _encoding.GetEncoder();
    } 

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
        if (disposing) 
            OutStream.Close();
    }
```

*MemoryStream*:

```
    public class MemoryStream : Stream
    {
        ....
    }
```

*Stream*

```
    public virtual void Close()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

---

To answer one of your further questions, "why can you still call .ToArray() if MemoryStream has been disposed", well, this test passes just fine:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDispose()
    {
        var m = new MemoryStream();
        m.WriteByte(120);
        m.Dispose();
        var a = m.ToArray();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, a.Length);
    }
```

So the `.ToArray()` method is still accessible after dispose.

The bytes are still available. `MemoryStream` dispose just sets some flags internally that prevent you from further modifying the stream:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
        try {
            if (disposing) {
                _isOpen = false;
                _writable = false; 
                _expandable = false;
                // Don't set buffer to null - allow GetBuffer & ToArray to work. 
            } 
        }
        finally { 
            // Call base.Close() to cleanup async IO resources
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

In fact, note that the source has the comment in it:

```
// Don't set buffer to null - allow GetBuffer & ToArray to work.
```

so that really answers that question :)

Comment: THIS DOES NOT THROW AN EXCEPTION. IT WORLKS PERFECT. The Binarywriter does not dispose of the memorystream.

Comment: `memorystream.Dispose();memorystream.Dispose();memorystream.Dispose();` doesn't trow exception either - so what exactly you are crying about?

Comment: The point is the memorystream.ToArray() does not throw an which it would if the memorystream was disposed of. The real question is why does code analyis flag this and suggest that I do no use the surrounding using which in fact causes the MemoryStream to not be disposed of. Im questioning the value of the VS code analysis tool.

Comment: Um, the tool is telling you that the memory stream is being disposed of twice, that is all. It is a *warning* not an *error*. It is just telling you that you have unnecessary code, not that your code is necessarily wrong. I guess I don't understand the -1 vote, because the answer is technically correct. It explains where the object is being disposed of twice, which causes the analysis warning.

Comment: Lots of objects can be disposed of `n` times if their implementations permit it. It doesn't mean that disposing objects twice is correct behaviour, though.

Comment: I added the source code for the .NET classes. You can clearly see that the .Dispose() call to MemoryStream causes its underlying stream to be closed, as I originally stated.

Comment: I added another edit to my answer to address your question about accessig the `.ToArray()` method after it has been disposed.